# Search by multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Suppose I have the following table:

[image]

My expectation is:

1. If I search nothing it will return all the rows of the table.
2. If I search--- 'sr' 'm', 'ap','null'---it will return only the first row
3. If I search--- 'null', 'm', 'ap','null ' ---it will return only the first two rows
4. If I search--- 'null', 'm', 'null  ','null' ---it will return only the first three rows
5. If I search--- 'null', 'm', ' tn','null' ---it will return only the third row

Any help please

Comment: Please show us the code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Sree',
        @city VARCHAR(100),
        @state VARCHAR(100)

;WITH test_table([name], city, state, country) AS
(
    SELECT 'Sree','mm','ap','ind' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xxx','mm','ap','ind' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abcd','mm','tn','ind' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wer','dd','ap','ind' 
)
SELECT * 
FROM test_table AS t
WHERE t.name = ISNULL(NULLIF(@name, ''), t.name)
  AND t.city = ISNULL(NULLIF(@city, ''), t.city)
  AND t.state = ISNULL(NULLIF(@state, ''), t.state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your inputs are in variables p_name, p_city and p_state, you can use case to do conditional filtering

```
Select *
From t
Where
Name = case when @p_name = '' then name else @p_name end
And city = case when @p_city = '' then city else @p_city end
And state = case when @p_state = '' then name else @p_state end;
```

To handle null also in variables, you can use:

```
Nullif(@var, '') is null
```